# Matlab 2017: In labeled binary image, fill the blobs with different colors

Tags: matlab, image-processing, colors

I have this labeled binary image with multiple blobs. I want to fill the labeled blobs with colors defined by me. For example: as shown in the image, blobs of labels 2,4 and 8, I want them to be filled with green color. Similarly, blobs of label 5,6, and 11, I want them to be filled with red color. Rest blobs should be filled with blue color. I know about  `label2rgb` command but don't know how to do this color filling with `label2rgb`.

How to do this? I'm using Matlab 2017.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
numlabels = max(L(:));
blue=[0,0,1];
red=[1,0,0];
green=[0,1,0];
cmap=repmat(blue, [numlabels, 1]); % create color map, default color is blue
cmap([2,4,8], :)=repmat(green, [3,1]); % change  color map to green for label 2,4,8
cmap([5,6,11], :)=repmat(red, [3,1]);  % change  color map to red for label 5,6,11
RGB2 = label2rgb(L,cmap,'k'); % 'k' is black background color, see help
imshow(RGB2)
```

Comment: Thanks @Alex Alex for your answer. It changes the color of blobs as I desired. But the background pixels color becomes white while it should be black only. How to solve this?

Comment: I change answer.